# Codeception $env is not accessible in integrational test after upgading to 2.2.5

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

I have upgraded my codeception version from `2.1.7` to `2.2.5.` In one integrational test case I am accessing current environment using:

`$this->env`

It was working fine in `2.1.7` version but in `2.2.5` version I am getting error:

```
Undefined property: tests\integrational\AutoBillerTest::$env
```

I checked in library and found that

`vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/TestCase/Shared/Actor.php`

file is not present in current version but it was present in previous version. This Actor class contains $env variable.

I tried to generate actor class using command:

`$codecept build`

Still that Actor class is not getting generated.

Answer (score 0):

Test formats were completely refactored in Codeception 2.2 and that Actor trait is gone.

In 2.2 enviroment can be retrieved from \Codeception\Scenario in Cept and Cest formats and from \Codeception\Metadata in Unit format (Scenario gets it from Metadata too).

Unit format:

```
$this->getMetadata()->getEnv()
```

In Cept format $scenario variable is always available, so you can simply do

```
$scenario->current('env');
```

In Cest format `$scenario` variable must be injected

```
public function tryToTest(UnitTester $I, \Codeception\Scenario $scenario)
{
    $scenario->current('env');
}
```

Usage of Scenario is [documented](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Current-values).

Comment: $this->getMetadata()->getEnv()  returns an empty array.

Comment: Please raise an issue at https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues This is a very specific issue.